# No such method "destroy" for Redactor

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm not sure if the word "method" pertains to a function or a class from the Redactor.  But I'm trying to destroy the redactor by `$('#id').redactor('destroy')`.  The code works when the redactor is created/instantiated, but gives an error **No such method "destroy" for Redactor** right after I destroy it, (since it is already destroyed). In a way I want to check if the method exist before I do the destroy; like the one from javascript to check if the function exist like `typeof $(#id).redactor === 'function'`, I also tried using `$(#id).hasClass($(#id).redactor('destroy'))`  which still results to the error.

So I'm not sure on how to check if the method exist, so that I will only destroy it if the redactor was created/instantiated.

For the sake of Mr Jadhav:

this is my Instructions.js

```
Ext.define('myNamespace', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    alias : 'widget.instructionstab',

    requires:[
        'myCommonFunctions',
    ],
    margin: '5 5 5 5',
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this,
            cfg = cfg || {};

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'textareafield',
                    flex: 1,
                    itemId: 'txtHeaderComment',
                    fieldLabel: 'Header Comment',
                    enableDrillDown: true,
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textareafield',
                    flex: 1,
                    itemId: 'txtFooterComment',
                    fieldLabel: 'Footer Comment',
                    enableDrillDown: true
                }
            ]
        }, cfg);

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }

});
```

myCommonFunctions:

```
createRadEditor: function(el) {
        var me = this;

        var fn = function () {
            $('#' + el.inputId).redactor({
                buttons: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'deleted', 'alignleft', 'aligncenter', 'alignright', 'unorderedlist', 'orderedlist', 'outdent', 'indent', 'image', 'video', 'table', 'link', 'horizontalrule', 'html', 'fullscreenwindow'],
                plugins: ['fontcolor', 'fontfamily', 'fullscreenwindow'],
                clipboardUpload: true,
                clipboardUploadUrl: './somelink/setimage',
                blurCallback: function(e){
                    console.log("ASDF"); // i'm still trying out something
                }
            });

            $('#'+ el.inputId).redactor('setTextEditorHeight');
            $('#'+ el.inputId).attr("id",el.config.itemId);
        };
        var task = Ext.create('Ext.util.DelayedTask', fn);
        task.delay(500);
    },
```

myView:

```
{
    xtype: 'panel',
    itemId: 'pnlInstructions',
    layout: 'fit',
    title: 'Instructions',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'instructionstab'
        }
    ]
},
```

I'm using some of the documentation here https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/ for the properties of the redactor.

Comment: where is `ExtJS` code?

Comment: My project is created in ext Js.. i just didn't place the code for the Ext js but I placed the tag coz I might not know something in Ext Js that could be used for replacement of the jquery, but the important part is just the jquery part... but if you really need I can provide...

Comment: If you are using ExtJS so try to use ExtJS method for get component instead of jquery.

Comment: I edited the info. Please Mr Jadhav.. enlighten me on the difference of using the extjs method of getting the component and how it will help with my problem on disabling the redactor

Comment: Mr JC please try this `$('#id').destroyEditor()` this will work. ref [link](https://imperavi.com/redactor/) and Please also check this [FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2f5s)

Answer (score 1):

if  you want to destroy redactor then you should use:

```
$("#editor").redactor("core.destroy");
```